# SharePoint API - callback for any document upload

Tags: sharepoint

Does SharePoint have a hook / API for getting notified whenever a document is added / modified /deleted?  I'd like to parse the document and send some of the information to another system.  Preferably, this would be on the server side of SharePoint.

Comment: You could create a workflow that fires when a new document is added to a library which would allow you to do stuff at that point...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [SharePoint event receivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg749858%28v=office.14%29.aspx).